# Ubuntu logo doesn't appear on startup

Tags: boot, startup, logo

I have Ubuntu 22.10. The logo doesn't appear on startup. All I get is a black screen with these sentences:

```
[    0.181917] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
/dev/sdb6: clean, 583900/4407696 files. 12949894/17583104 blocks
[    10.027091] snd_hda_codec_conexant hdaudioCODO: vmaster hook already present before cdev!
```

I tried the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
Choose /usr/share/plymouth/themes/bgrt/bgrt.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

But It didn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: Does it boot okay?

Comment: @Rishon_JR Yes, it does.

Comment: Or you are changing the logo and it doesn't show up?

Comment: @Rishon_JR I expect to see hp and Ubuntu logos, but I don't see either.

Comment: Okay sorry i didn't see your comment. You wanted the factory defaults so boot into a ;live USB and select "Try Ubuntu". Then mount your disk using `gnome-disks` and check where it is mounted at using `lsblk`. then do `cp -r /usr/share/plymouth /dev/<disk mount>/usr/share/plymouth`. Reboot back to the the HDD and run `sudo update-initramfs -u && sudo update-grub`. Reboot and Rejoice :D. Please update me if this works for you

Comment: @Rishon_JR I don't know what to say. I did something fool. At first I tried everything and it didn't work, so I decided to try again but delete plymouth first. I accidentally deleted the share folder. I had to reinstall Ubuntu. At least it worked.........

Comment: Okay, glad it worked... Before you do anything next time duplicate the default ubuntu theme and make modifications.

Comment: @Rishon_JR Okay, on the fresh installation of Ubuntu, after opening it for the third time, the logos don't appear again, no matter how many times I reboot. I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144301/discussion-between-ezzeldien-rashad-and-rishon-jr).

Comment: @Rishon_JR In case you want to know, the logos stopped appearing again. Now every time I reboot, The above sentences appear then disappear quickly and an underscore appears there at the top. I think I will just ignore this. Sorry If I bothered you.

Comment: Yeah it's fine.